# VS2017 Issue Connecting to TFS and VSTS with same account

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I am trying to move a single solutions from on-prem TFS to VSTS. I am using VS2017 as the IDE and have unbound all the projects in the solution from TFS. Both TFS and VSTS use our AD credentials. When I try to connect to VSTS is says to use the existing account in the dropdown. That probably isn't enough information, but I'm not sure what else to add. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: So what's the problem when you connect to VSTS with the same account? any error or warning messages there?

Comment: I ended up contacting the team on twitter and resolved this issue by fixing the VS install

Answer (score 0):

After talking with MSFT on Twitter I have this. If this issue persists and you are able to connect to the repository via another machine then run a fix on Visual Studio